# Marking Cross-Posted Questions

Tags: support, mathoverflow, cross-posting

I have come across several questions which have been cross-posted to MO with no clear indication, such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527495/a-question-about-the-divisibility-of-sum-of-2-consecutive-primes?noredirect=1#comment7806473_527495) question cross-posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145263/a-question-about-the-divisibility-of-sum-of-2-consecutive-primes), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750621/a-nice-problem-in-additive-number-theory) question cross-posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365527/a-nice-problem-in-additive-combinatorics) (note the second example has been edited to disclose the cross-posting, but this was not the case right away as can be seen from the comments).

Of course, if I am unaware that such a question has been cross-posted, the best I can do is ask in the comments. However, if I know that a questions has indeed been cross-posted, should I

- Edit the original question to include a link to the cross post?
- Post a comment with the link?
- Flag the post as a duplicate to keep only the MO version?

To me, it seems that the first two options make most sense. What is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Either of the first two options, I think are appropriate.

Comment: Commonly a comment with the link gets posted, which highlights the fact that the OP did not advise us of the cross-posting.  This is generally a problem only with new users.

Comment: The crossposting notice makes it easier for both sides to work out whether or not their copy should be closed, and for users to get to the answer if either one is closed.